# preg_replace, clickable tags Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, function, tags, preg-replace

If a user writes a post he has the possibility to use hashtags in the text.
the text is saved as body in the post table. A hashtag is a word that starts with a #. The hashtags are stored in a tag table and have a many-to-many relationship to the posts.

```
if($post)
{
    preg_match_all('/#(\w+)/', $request->get('body'),$tagNames);
    // $tagnames contains an array of results. $tagnames[0] is all matches
    $tagIds = [];
    foreach($tagNames[0] as $tagName)
    {
        //$post->tags()->create(['name'=>$tagName]);
        //Or to take care of avoiding duplication of Tag
        //you could substitute the above line as
        $tag = Tag::firstOrCreate(['name'=>$tagName]);
        if($tag)
        {
            $tagIds[] = $tag->id;
        }

    }
    $post->tags()->sync($tagIds);
}
```

So I give the data to the view:

```
$postall = $user->posts()->with('comments', 'tags')->where('status', 1)->latest()->get();
```

Each hashtag has its own view which can be reached under /tags/id. Now I want to replace the hashtags in the text with an a href element pointing to the respective view. I've read that with preg_replace is possible, but how and where do I have to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Check content for **each tag**

*I assumed you have `$post->content`* and *your tags show route's name  is `tags.show`*

```
foreach($post->tags as $tag){

   $link = '<a href="'.route('tags.show',$tag->title).'">'.$tag->title.'</a>';

   str_replace($tag->title,$link,$post->content);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, your code is not working. The hashtags in the text are not replaced with an a href link.

Answer (score 0):

In your view...within the foreach of the content, you can:

```
{!!str_replace($tag->name,"<a href='your-tag-route/$tag->id'>$tag->name</a>",$tag->name)!!}
```

Search for `$tag->name`

Replace with `<a href> and your route`

Within: `$post->content`

## EDIT 1:

You can replace the tags within the content, the moment they are pulled-in:
In your model:

```
Post.php
```

Create a function that will decorate the content of the body attribute by pulling-in the tags, and replacing the content of each occurrence with your pattern. 
At your return, the $content that shows on your view will be the redecorated valued.

```
public function getBodyAttribute ($value){
        $tags = Tag::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
        $replacement =  '<a alt="$1" href="/tags/$1">$1</a>';
        $pattern = '/\b('.implode('|', $tags).')/i';
        return $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $value);
    }
```

Lastly on your view, use {!! $post->body !!}

## EDIT2:

To change and use the Tag name as the key for the table, add this to your Tag model page:

```
public function getRouteKeyName(){
     return 'name';
}
```

From now on, anytime you `Tag::find()`, instead of using `id` you use the `name`.
For example, `Tag::find(php)`

You need consistency of the characters (either to always be saved as small letters or big), so, on your Tag model add this:

```
public function setNameAttribute ($name){
    $this->attributes['name'] = strtolower($name);
}
```

Before saving to the db, it converts all tags to small letters for sake of consistency.

These solve your second problem of calling `<a href="/tags/du"> #du </a>` directly.

Note that you dont need to change the replacement code above. I forgot to add #, so this will suffice:

```
$replacement =  '<a alt="$1" href="/tags/$1">#$1</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The post-> body does not know what word is a tag, so the code does not work unfortunately.

Comment: Edited..check now.

Comment: thanks, it does not work perfectly yet. Your code has all the words in the database changed to an a href element without function.

I changed the code a bit:
`public function getBodyAttribute ($ value) {
        $ replacement = '<a href="/tags/$1"> # $ 1 </a>';
        $ pattern = '/ # (\ w +) /';
        return $ content = preg_replace ($ pattern, $ replacement, $ value);
    }`

Comment: The problem is, the a href element is displayed in the text and has no function. In the text it looks like this:

`<a href="/tags/du"> #du </a>`

The second problem is, I need the ID in the URL and not the tag. Unfortunately, I do not know how I can solve the problem.

Comment: 1st problem is actually the way it was supposed to work. It changes the occurrence of the tag name to href tag...yes. However, as I mentioned in the last statement of the message above, I wrote, use {!!$post->body!!} in your view...instead of {{$post->body}} this is what changes and converts the href tags to normal, clickable tags. 2nd problem is easily solvable...if the tags are one words each, just turn them into keys. I will post the code below.

Comment: thanks it works fine. But how can I show the tagname on a page? That does not work anymore.

Comment: How are you showing it before...? Within the post's foreach or separately?

Comment: separately on the tag view with `{{$tag->name}}` but now ich get a error message: `Trying to get property of non-object.`  `public function show($name)
    {
        $tag = Tag::find($name);
        $tagcount = ??;

        return view('tag', compact('tag', 'tagcount'));
    }`
how can I show on the view page how often the tag was used?

Comment: If I get you correctly, you want a stat that shows how many times a particular tag has been used overall...? If thats so, then simple. Since you already have a relatiosnhip with the post, just call it off of it. Like: $tag->post()->count() It returns an integer. No need to pass that $tagcount variable.  As for the error, can you confirm within your show method, what does this dd($tag) return?

Comment: I used `$tag->post()->count()`, but I get the same error message.     
 dd($tag) returns "null"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164783/discussion-between-wale-and-slickness).